# Jquery Remove TR with Event and immediate TR Above it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic table calendar that displays a row of "No Events Today" when there are no events for that day.

I'm trying to remove the TR for this particular content **INCLUDING** the TR immediately above it, however **only** when the particular TR displays "No Events Today".

This is the jQuery I came up with so far that half works, since it removes the content, but I need your help with the removing the date, too.

```
$("tr td:contains('No events today')").parent().remove();
```

My [Demo](http://jsbin.com/viwuwixa/1/)

This is stripped down example of the table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="CalendarEventDate" colspan="3">Saturday, March 1 2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="CalendarNoEvent" colspan="3">No events today</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="CalendarEventDate" colspan="3">Sunday, March 2 2014</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="CalendarEventTime">All Day</td>
        <td class="CalendarEventName"><a href="http://www.example.com">Event Name Here</a></td>
        <td class="CalendarEventLocation">Remote</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: why dont use the class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("tr td:contains('No events today')").parent().hide().prev('tr').hide()`

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the previous sibling of the tr-element which encapsulates the td-element with "No events today" as well.

jQuery provides the [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) function.

Something like this shoudl work:

```
$("tr td:contains('No events today')").parent().prev().remove();
```

Comment: Try to alert `$("tr td:contains('No events today')").parent().prev().html()` and try to alert `$("tr td:contains('No events today')").parents('tr').html()`

Comment: Oh, just re-read the OP's question, So, he wants to remove tr with `No events today` as well as the previous tr with the date. Anyway, your code is only partially works, it doesn't remove `No events today` table row

Comment: Well, if you try it on the jsbin you'll get undefined in case you have Auto-run JS checked because there're no more td-elements which contain "no events today".

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [jQuery.prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/). See the following example.

```
//Find the first td.
var tr = $("tr td:contains('No events today')").parent();
//Find the previous element and remove it from the DOM.
tr.prev().remove();//Could be written tr.prev(".CalendarEventDate").remove();
//No remove the first td from the DOM.
tr.remove();
```